# asp.net/javascript, why is textbox onChange event does not fire?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I want it to happen when after user select the userID then the userID show up on first readonly textbox then the `onChange` event should fire when it show on first readonly textbox so it can copy this userID to second textbox. However it doesn't work, it only worked is the userID show up on first textbox but the onChange doesn't trigger for second texbox.

Here half working codes:

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">
        Secondary Owner
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbAdd_Sowner" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
        <input id="Hidden2" type="hidden" />
        <input id="Hidden3" type="hidden" />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="GalModalTOCCDialog(Hidden1, tbAdd_Sowner, Hidden2,Hidden3)">
            Get User ID</a>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" ValidationGroup="g1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required" ControlToValidate="tbAdd_Sowner"> <b style="color:Red;"> * </b></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender8" runat="server" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator7">
        </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right">Secondary Owners</td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbAdd_Sphone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" ValidationGroup="g1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required" ControlToValidate="tbAdd_Sphone"> <b style="color:Red;"> * </b></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender9" runat="server" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator13">
        </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then a javascript codes in `<head>` to copy first textbox value and put to second textbox:

```
 <script>
        function getUserID() {
            document.getElementById('tbAdd_Sphone').value = document.getElementById('tbAdd_Sowner').value;
        }

document.getElementById('tbAdd_Sowner').onchange = getUserID();

            </script>
```

**Edited:** I add a GALModalDialog.js codes here because some of you want to see what it like. I also have GALToCCDialong.asp that listed userid to choose and XMLGALListbox.asp that get the userid from ADs.

```
function PopulateListboxFromString(oListbox,vNames,vUserIDs){

    var oArrayUserNames = vNames.value.split(';');
    var oArrayUserIDs = vUserIDs.value.split(';');

    for (var index=0;index < oArrayUserIDs.length;index++) {

        if (oArrayUserNames[index] != ''){
            var oOption = document.createElement("OPTION");
            oListbox.options.add(oOption);
            oOption.innerText = oArrayUserNames[index];
            oOption.value = oArrayUserIDs[index];
        }
    }   
};

function GalModalTOCCDialog(oTONames, oTOUserIDs,oCCNames, oCCUserIDs ) {


        if (oCCNames != null){

            var oInputArray = new Array(oTONames.value,oTOUserIDs.value,oCCNames.value,oCCUserIDs.value);

        } else {

            var oInputArray = new Array(oTONames.value,oTOUserIDs.value,'','');

        }

        var oOutputArray = window.showModalDialog('GalAccess/GALToCCDialog.asp', oInputArray, 'dialogWidth:510px;dialogHeight:400px;status:no;help:no;');





        // Check if we get something back; 
        // User might have closed the window without using the buttons
        if (oOutputArray != null){

            //first element is true if user clicked OK

            if (oOutputArray[0]) {

                if (oCCNames != null){

                    oTONames.value = oOutputArray[1];
                    oTOUserIDs.value = oOutputArray[2];
                    oCCNames.value = oOutputArray[3];
                    oCCUserIDs.value = oOutputArray[4];

                } else {

                    oTONames.value = oOutputArray[1];
                    oTOUserIDs.value = oOutputArray[2];     
                }



            } 
        }

    return false;
}

function GalModalDialog(oSelectObject, oUserID) {

    if (oUserID == null){
        // there is a select object to fill data from
        // fill the input array
        var oInputArray = new Array(new Array(oSelectObject.options.length),new Array(oSelectObject.options.length));

        for (var index=0;index < oInputArray[0].length;index++) {
            oInputArray[0][index] = oSelectObject.options[index].innerText;
            oInputArray[1][index] = oSelectObject.options[index].value;

        };

        var oOutputArray = window.showModalDialog('../GALDialog/GALModalDialog.asp', oInputArray, 'dialogWidth:500px;dialogHeight:320px;status:no;help:no;');

        // Check if we get something back; 
        // User might have closed the window without using the buttons
        if (oOutputArray != null){

            //first element is true if user clicked OK

            if (oOutputArray[0]) {
                //remove existing from end to beginning otherwise not all options are removed.

                var length=oSelectObject.options.length;
                for (var index=length-1;index >= 0;index--) {
                    oSelectObject.options[index] = null;
                };

                // copy the array   
                for (var index=0;index < oOutputArray[1].length;index++) {
                    var oOption = document.createElement("OPTION");
                    oSelectObject.options.add(oOption);
                    oOption.innerText = oOutputArray[1][index];
                    oOption.value = oOutputArray[2][index];

                };
            } 
        }
    } else
    {
        // there are 2 text objects to fill data from; the first contains the name, the secound the userid.
        //if (oSelectObject.value != '' ) {
        //  var oInputArray = new Array(new Array(1),new Array(1));
        //
        //  oInputArray[0][0] = oSelectObject.value;
        //  oInputArray[1][0] = oUserID.value;

        //} else {

                var oInputArray = new Array(new Array(0),new Array(0));

        //}     
        var oOutputArray = window.showModalDialog('../GALDialog/GALModalDialog.asp', oInputArray, 'dialogWidth:500px;dialogHeight:320px;status:no;help:no;');

        if (oOutputArray != null){

            //first element is true if user clicked OK

            if (oOutputArray[0]) {

                // copy the data    
                oSelectObject.value = oOutputArray[1][0];
                oUserID.value = oOutputArray[2][0];


            } 
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Edited:** Here is codes of GALToCCDialog.asp. In `SubmitOnclick` function and `else if(vAction == 'OK')` is where I click OK button from selected userid to submit to textbox.

```
<SCRIPT ID=clientEventHandlersJS LANGUAGE=javascript>
<!--

function List_onkeydown(oList) {

    if( event.keyCode == 46 ){

        if ((oList.selectedIndex != -1)&&(oList.options[oList.selectedIndex].value != '')){
            oList.options[oList.selectedIndex] = null;

        }
    }
}

//-->
</SCRIPT>


<script language="jscript">



function InitializeListbox(idXML, idSpan){

    // get to the XML specifying the names
    var oSelects;
    var strXML;

    oSelects  = idXML.XMLDocument.documentElement.childNodes;
    strXML = '';
    // Get all the options in 1 string
    for (var index=0;index< oSelects.length;index++){
        strXML = strXML + oSelects[index].xml;
    }
    // the error handlingis there if idSpan refers to multiple objects

    // Insert the options in the html before the end of the SELECT
    // window.alert(strXML);
    //idSpan.innerHTML = replace(idSpan.innerHTML,"</SELECT>",strXML & "</SELECT>");
    idSpan.innerHTML = '<SELECT id=idUserSelect size=12 style="width:190px">' + strXML + '</SELECT>';
}

function SubmitOnclick(vAction, oObject){

    //DistList.action = "DistList.asp?Action=" & vAction ;

    if (vAction == 'Add'){

        if ((idUserSelect.value!='')&&(idUserSelect.value!='Unknown')){
            var oOption = document.createElement("OPTION");
            oObject.options.add(oOption);
            oOption.innerText = idUserSelect.options[idUserSelect.selectedIndex].text;
            oOption.value = idUserSelect.options[idUserSelect.selectedIndex].value;
        }
    }   else if(vAction == 'Find') {
        idXMLUsers.src ='XMLGALListbox.asp?Searchstring=' + SearchString.value;

    } else if(vAction == 'Remove'){

        if ((idMyList.selectedIndex != -1)&&(idMyList.options[idMyList.selectedIndex].value != '')){
            idMyList.options[idMyList.selectedIndex] = null;
        }
    } else if(vAction == 'OK'){

        //window.returnValue = cal.day + ' ' + MonthNames[cal.month-1] + ' ' + cal.year ;
        // create an array

        var TONames = ''
        var TOUserIDs = ''
        var CCNames = ''
        var CCUserIDs = ''

        for (var index = 0; index < 1; index++) {
            TONames = TONames + idTOList.options[index].innerText;
            TOUserIDs = TOUserIDs + idTOList.options[index].value;
        };

        //Commented out by Nick, use if you want multiple userIDs etc...
        //for (var index=0;index < idTOList.options.length;index++) {
        //  TONames = TONames + idTOList.options[index].innerText  ;
        //  TOUserIDs = TOUserIDs + idTOList.options[index].value ;         
        //};

        //for (var index=0;index < idCCList.options.length;index++) {
            //CCNames = CCNames + idCCList.options[index].innerText ;
            //CCUserIDs = CCUserIDs + idCCList.options[index].value ;

        //};

        var oArray = new Array(true,TONames,TOUserIDs,CCNames,CCUserIDs);

        window.returnValue = oArray;

        //window.alert(TONames);
        //window.alert(TOUserIDs);
        //window.alert(CCNames);
        //window.alert(CCUserIDs);

        window.close();

    } else if(vAction == 'Cancel'){
        var oArray = new Array(false);
        window.returnValue = oArray;
        window.close();

    }   

}

function OnBodyLoad() {

    //window.alert('test');
    //clear all list data

    try{
        var oArray = window.dialogArguments;

        //PopulateListboxFromString(idTOList,oArray[0],oArray[1])
        //PopulateListboxFromString(idCCList,oArray[2],oArray[3])

    } catch(e)
    {
    }

};

function PopulateListboxFromString(oListbox,vNames,vUserIDs){

    var oArrayUserNames = vNames.split(';');
    var oArrayUserIDs = vUserIDs.split(';');
    for (var index=0;index < oArrayUserIDs.length;index++) {

        if (oArrayUserNames[index] != ''){
            var oOption = document.createElement("OPTION");
            oListbox.options.add(oOption);
            oOption.innerText = oArrayUserNames[index];
            oOption.value = oArrayUserIDs[index];
        }
    }   

};

function OnBodyLoad__() {

    //window.alert('test');
    try{
        var oArray = window.dialogArguments;

        for (var index=0;index < oArray[0].length;index++) {
            var oOption = document.createElement("OPTION");
            idMyList.options.add(oOption);
            oOption.innerText = oArray[0][index];
            oOption.value = oArray[1][index];

        };
    } catch(e)
    {

    };
};

</script>
<body class="cellcolorlightest content" onload="OnBodyLoad();">
<xml id="idXMLUsers" src="XMLGALListbox.asp?Searchstring=" ondatasetcomplete="InitializeListbox(idXMLUsers, idUsers);"></xml>

    <table class="TableBorderNormal" width="100%" border=0 cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="50%"></col><col></col><col width="50%"></col>
        <thead>

        <tr>
         <td colspan="3" class="TDvwvInfo" align="left"><STRONG>Find Name</STRONG><br><FONT size=2>Type name and hit "Search"</FONT></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
         <td  class="TDvwvInfo" align="left"><input name="SearchString" style="WIDTH: 190px" size="20"> &nbsp;</td>
         <td class="TDvwvInfo" align="middle" valign=top><input  type="button" value="Search" name="Find" onclick="SubmitOnclick('Find')"></td>
         <td class="TDvwvInfo" align="left"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
         <td class="TDvwvInfo" align="left" nowrap><STRONG>Users found</STRONG><br><FONT size=2>Select from list and hit "Select" to add</FONT></td>
         <td class="TDvwvInfo" align="middle"></td>
         <td class="TDvwvInfo" align="left" valign=top><STRONG>Get User ID</STRONG><br></td>
        </tr>

        </thead>

        <tr>
         <td class="TDvwv" align="left" width="33%" rowspan=2  valign=top><span id="idUsers">   </span> </td>               
         <td class="TDvwvInfo" align="middle" valign=top width="33%">
         <input  type="button" value="Select &gt;" name="Add" onclick="SubmitOnclick('Add', idTOList);"><br><br>&nbsp;
         </td>
         <td class="TDvwv" align="left" width="33%"  valign=top>
          <select id="idTOList" size="5" style="WIDTH: 190px" LANGUAGE=javascript onkeydown="return List_onkeydown(this)"> </select><br>&nbsp;
          <br />
          <b style="color:red">* Only add one user, if you added the wrong user click cancel and try again.</b>
          </td>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                 <td align=middle  valign=top>
                 <!-- <input type="hidden" value="CC  >" name="CC" onclick="SubmitOnclick('Add', idCCList);" disabled="disabled"><br><br>&nbsp;--> <!--INPUT name=Remove onclick="SubmitOnclick('Remove');" type=button value="  < Remove"--></td>
                 <td align=left  valign=top>
                  <!--<select id=idCCList size=5 style="WIDTH: 190px" LANGUAGE=javascript onkeydown="return List_onkeydown(this)" disabled="disabled" visible="false"></select></td>-->

            </tr>

        <tr>
         <td align="middle" ></td>
         <td align=middle></td>
         <td align=left>
          <input type="button" value="OK" name="OK" onclick="SubmitOnclick('OK',null);">&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="Cancel" onclick="SubmitOnclick('Cancel',null);"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you would need to use ClientID of the server control i think. and you are trying to addEventListener outside the function.

Comment: The userID is already insert to tbAdd_Sowner after selected. onChange should trigger when it inserted.

Comment: you are trying to addEventListener outside the function.. isn't this the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
document.getElementById('<%= tbAdd_Sphone.ClientID %>')
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('tbAdd_Sphone')
```

[MSDN Control.ClientID Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx)

Comment: I got error for that, Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: This is because the Gridview is generating the id runtime. So can do it by looping through gridview rows though

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. I already have the userId inserted in tbAdd_Sowner. After I select, it automatic paste to this text box then it should fire to copy it.

Comment: I check for alert. It show that onChange does not trigger because the alert popup window never show up.

Comment: You are manually putting text in the first textbox or assigning it against some event?

Comment: I do not manually putting text in first textbox. The function should automatic itself put text in first textbox after I select the text

Comment: This issue still not solved? send me your files i will look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make change event just by setting value from javascript. Here is a sample by using trigger.

```
 <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {

           $(".tbAdd_Sowner").on('change', function () {
               var owner = $('.tbAdd_Sowner').val();
               $('.tbAdd_Sphone').val(owner);
           });

           $(".aGetID").on('click', function () {
               var tbOwner = $('.tbAdd_Sowner');
               var hidden1 = $('.Hidden1');
               var hidden2 = $('.Hidden2');
               var hidden3 = $('.Hidden3');
               GalModalTOCCDialog(hidden1, tbOwner, hidden2, hidden3);

           });

           function GalModalTOCCDialog(Hidden1, tbAdd_Sowner, Hidden2, Hidden3) {
               $(tbAdd_Sowner).val(' ').trigger('change');
           }

           $('.tbAdd_Sowner').change(function () {
               $(this).removeAttr('disabled');

           });
       });
    </script>
```

Here is your code, removing those validators

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Secondary Owner
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" value="1" class="Hidden1"  />
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbAdd_Sowner" OnTextChanged="tbAdd_Sowner_TextChanged" CssClass="tbAdd_Sowner" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Enabled="false"   ></asp:TextBox>
                <input id="Hidden2" type="hidden" class="Hidden2" />
                <input id="Hidden3" type="hidden" class="Hidden3" />
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="aGetID" class="aGetID" >Get User ID</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Secondary Owners</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbAdd_Sphone" runat="server" CssClass="tbAdd_Sphone" ></asp:TextBox>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Server side.

```
protected void tbAdd_Sowner_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbAdd_Sowner.Text = "123";
        }
```

Comment: I don't see GalModalTOCCDialog script file. That is responsible to get AD names, uid, and etcs.

Comment: see Jquery #aGetID click event. YOu can get textobx values there too using $('#tbAdd_Sowner').val()

Comment: well I didn't delete `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="GalModalTOCCDialog(ToName2, tbAdd_Powner, CCName2,CCUserID2)">`. But I add `<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="aGetID" >Get User Name</a>` and it doesn't work


                                                        Get User ID</a>

Comment: @StudentIT: ok you can check the Jquery now. I added your function back.

Comment: You cannot assume that "tbAdd_Sowner" remains the same since it is a server control. Depending on your settings, it is very likely that the ID changes is something like "ctl14_tbAdd_Sowner".

Comment: @StudentIT: just to be sure, are you aware of what happens client-side in the browser and what happens serverside?
The question is also if you require a ASP.NET server control or maybe a HTML input element is enough. And where do you SELECT the user ID? Could you provide that part too?

Comment: @StudentIT: Ok I have made modification in the code. Its firing server side event now.
I sent a trigger on client side to fire textchange event. When the client side fire textchange then I removed the disabled attribute to fire the server side textchange event. After postback occurs the disabled attribute will be restored automatically.

Comment: @StudentIT: Seems like you have kept your controls inside update panels, so  you get the ID starting with ct_XXX. Hence I used the CSS class attribute to find the controls. It remains the same, no matter on which panel you keep.

Comment: I did tried what you modify. When I click "Get User ID", The window does not pop up for me to select the user ID. I added `GalModalTOCCDialog.js` codes in case you wanted to see what it like.

Comment: @StudentIT: Ok here's the idea. Remove my function GalModalTOCCDialog and call your function GalModalTOCCDialog so the popup will show up. Once you are done selecting your ID then on that button click event or anything just call  $(tbAdd_Sowner).val(yourvalue).trigger('change').

Comment: Look at what I edited from above by adding `GALToCCDialog.asp` on below example is where I click OK button to submit selected userid.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the value of `tbAdd_Sowner` through JavaScript (I assume through your `GalModalTOCCDialog` function) isn't going to fire the `onchange` event.

You can fire that event manually, after you set the value:

```
document.getElementById('tbAdd_Sowner').onchange();
```

Though I'm surprised you aren't have problems with `getElementById` like @IrfanTahirKheli showed, which should've worked fine for you... so there are likely missing pieces of your markup that we need to help you correctly.

Other things you need to strongly consider is to not use inline styling and not use tables for formatting.

Since you seem to have problems with what I added, here is another way. Remove the `onChange` from your `asp:TextBox` and just do it all from javascript:

```
 document.getElementById('tbAdd_Sowner').value = 'somevalue';
 document.getElementById('tbAdd_Sowner').onchange = getUserID();
```

Comment: 'tbAdd_Sowner' id did not change after rendering because OP did not use any container. You can find details here - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx)- in description of `AutiID`. I would say using client Id may save us in many places, but probably not here.

Comment: @afzalulh Most likely, yes, the ID has changed on render. It doesn't matter if it is in a container or not. It is a server control.

Comment: Please check the link. Or test yourself with a server control in a page(without masterpage), and see rendered ID.

Comment: @afzalulh OK you are right if he isn't using masterpage. But since the ClientID didn't work for him you notice I left it out of my answer to begin with ;)

Comment: +1 @MikeSmithDev - I would have same answer for OP. About the ID, I tested his code putting the tr in a table and it gives me correct id: why should I bother about master page while he did not mention :-)

Comment: Sorry took a while to response. Yes I do use Master Page

Comment: So I put document.getElementById('tbAdd_Sowner').onchange("change", getUserID); so it can call getUserID function?

Comment: No. You use the code I show, which will trigger the "onchange" function for `tbAdd_Sowner`, which you declared in `<asp:TextBox ID="tbAdd_Sowner" onChange="getUserID();"`...

Comment: ok I did add that but nothing happen. I do see the readonly first textbox showed up which it should trigger it(I didn't manually input first textbox. The javascript automatic put text in textbox after I select it). I add alert in getUserID() function and it doesn't pop up alert.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev After I click Get User ID. I type name of person and GalModalTOCCDialog responsible to search that name then display name found. I select the name then click ok. After click ok, the this script automatic pass user id(U078058) to textbox tbAdd_Sowner which it show up itself. Then second textbox tbAdd_Sphone should have copy U078058 from tbAdd_Sowner textbox to show up on tbAdd_Sowner textbox. I add `document.getElementById('tbAdd_Sowner').onchange();` as you say and I guess it will call function getUserID() so it can pass to tbAdd_Sphone?

Comment: @StudentIT the code works fine for me. Without more code detail in your question, I don't know how else to help. Consider adding relevant code from `GalModalTOCCDialog(`.

Comment: I don't think it needed to show codes from GalModalTOCCDialog(codes too long because of ADS search function). They worked fine and it passed string variable to tbAdd_Sowner textbox which it visable displayed on textbox. I just need to get that textbox value.

Comment: I can but I want to use trigger function for different purpose. For real purpose is when I get the uid shown on first textbox, I will use that value pass to XML website to get phone number and have that phone number show up on tbAdd_Sphone. I just want the trigger function onchange to work so I can do the rest of it.

Comment: @StudentIT Considering the textbox is read only, why do you even need a change event? Why don't you just call `getUserID();` after you set the value, instead of triggering the change event?

Comment: @StudentIT added another option.

Comment: I edited it and still does not response to this function. Was it because it located in `<head>` instead of `<body>`? Because `<body id="mybodyID" onload="GetHeight()">` seem to only call GetHeight in `<head>` instead of rest of others.

Comment: @StudentIT The edit you just made DOESN'T do what I showed. You can't just put that line in the head and expect it to work, as the element doesn't exist at that point. You should put that line AFTER the line of code where you set the value of tbAdd_Sowner (...which you don't show).

Comment: The one who pass to set a value is external GALToCCDialog.asp file which I added above on `SubmitOnClick` function when user click OK. I added that code you suggested and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

use this `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
            onkeypress="document.getElementById('id').Value=this.value;" />`

Answer (score 0):

Like others have mentioned in their answers,

```
  <asp:TextBox id="tbAdd_Sphone" runat="server" />
```

will have a server-side dynamic client-ID prefixed to the generated HTML. If you see the source code of the page (or use the developer tools) in a browser of choice, you will notice you the ID is different than what you are passing in to your method call i.e something like this:

```
<textarea id="ctl00_OuterASPControlID_tbADD_Sphone"></textarea>
```

You can keep the className static by using class="tbAdd_Sphone" if the class is dynamically prefixed too. Or, try to get element by ID on

```
<%=tbAdd_Sphone.ClientID %>
```

[You can either set the ClientID mode to static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), or you can try using UniqueID.

Another thing to note, javascript has a special behavior. If you call of a method with a set number of variables passed in correctly in the call, it will only use those values in the functionality. If there is null/undefined data passed into the call, the rest of the parameters are just ignored.

```
functionName:function(parameter1, parameter2) { 

            //Default behavior can be overridden if parameter2 is not passed in as expected.
            if(parameter2 ==null || parameter2=='undefined') { 
                parameter2 = "Some value"; 
                    } 
}


    functionName("testPar1");               //Works but parameter2 is not passed in as expected
    functionName("testPar1", "testPar2");   //Works
    functionName("testPar1", undefined);    //Works, but parameter2 is not passed in as expected
```

If you need to use the id for phone, either do a substring search for getting the element by the actual ID, or use a getElementsByTag in your javascript to search for textboxes, and you can use any other property, say in plain Javascript:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTag("textbox"); 
if(x!=null && x.attribute('class') == 'tbAdd_Sphone' )  { 
 var valueX = x.attribute('value'); 
}
```